# Duplicate canned comments from Low Quality Posts review queue

Tags: bug, comments, review, low-quality-posts

I'm not sure what happened [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/89490), but it seems like some kind of race condition and/or incomplete review item submission. Anyway, there's a 100% duplicate comment by the same user. Even the link is identical:

[image]

The user only appears once in the review task summary though:

[image]

For comparison, when *another* user doing the same review task chooses the same canned comment, this doesn't result in a new comment; rather, the existing comment is upvoted. Of course, that shouldn't happen here either; you can never upvote your own comment.